# Trouble with displaying images tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Images pass on top each other.

```
def show_ucgen():
    image = Image.open("image.png")
    image_resized = image.resize((256, 256))
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_resized)
    label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master,text = "", image=photo).place(x=150, y=30)
    label.pack()

    
def show_kare():
    image1 = Image.open("kare.png")
    image1_resized = image1.resize((256, 256))
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1_resized)
    label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master,text = "", image=photo).place(x=150, y=30)
    label.pack()


def show_daire():
    image2 = Image.open("daire.png")
    image2_resized = image2.resize((256, 256))
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image2_resized)
    label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master,text = "", image=photo).place(x=120, y=30)
    label.pack()
```

Its expected to remove the image while opening another.

Comment: _"Its expected to remove the image while opening another."_ - why do you expect that, since you create a new label each time without destroying the old labels?

Comment: To piggyback off of @BryanOakley, why not just update an existing label rather than having three separate labels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only be using one geometry manager (`pack`, `place`, or `grid`) on any given widget.

Instead of:

```
label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master,text = "", image=photo).place(x=150, y=30)
label.pack()
```

Try using only `place` *or* `pack` (I tend to prefer `pack`)

```
label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master,text = "", image=photo)
label.pack()
```

You may want to tell the labels to `expand` and `fill` as well

```
#example
label.pack(expand=True, fill='both')  # 'both' meaning x and y axes
```

Another important note is that all of the geometry manager methods return `None`, so what's happening here is that each of your `label`s is evaluating to `None`. When you `pack` them you are trying to `pack` `None` instead of an instance of `Label`. For this reason, you should always instantiate your widgets separately from adding them to a geometry manager:

```
my_label = Label(master).pack()  # NO - my_label is now None
```

```
my_label = Label(master)
my_label.pack()  # YES - my_label is an instance of Label
```

Comment: So how can I place the photo where I want?

Comment: You can use `place` instead of `pack` if you absolutely need pixel-perfect control over where things are put. I didn't mean to imply that you shouldn't use `place` *at all*; only that you should use one geometry manager per-widget! For most cases, `place` makes GUI design more finicky, but if your goal is exact positioning it's definitely the thing to use. Just do `label.pack(x=150, y=30)` (or whatever x/y you need) instead.

Comment: def temizle():


    label.destroy()

I made a function to clear the photo from the screen with button but I couldn't manage to make it work. Can you help?

Comment: You can use `label.place_forget()` to remove the label. If you're still running into issues, submit a new question with your revised code. Also, if this answer worked for you, please mark it as 'Accepted' so others know this question has been answered.